# Bluehost Symfony Shared Hosting Database parameters.yml settings Issue

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, shared-hosting

I'm stuck trying to get my symfony 2.8.1 app to connect to my database on bluehost. Included below are my settings:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
```

What are the correct settings? I've used mysql before without having to specify my port and it works fine but that doesn't work with symfony. All my routes are working fine but can't authenticate users because the app can't connect to the database.

Comment: Bit surprising to see a database_host of 127.0.0.1 on a shared host.  You are sure you did not specify something like db.bluehost.com when you used  mysql on cluehost before?  Might want to double check the site's instructions.  And maybe check your database name as well: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/318

Comment: @Cerad $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); where $servername = "localhost" . This has worked fine for me. But specify localhost and setting port to null, doesn't work for me.

Comment: And $dbname is of the form username_dbname?  You are sure that new PDO() is throwing an exception?  Checked the logs and what not?

Comment: @Cerad Yes the $dname is in the form username_dbname. In symfony all you need to do is set the parameters in parameters.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluehost uses settings similar to the following:

```
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     localhost
database_port:     ~
database_name:     (cpanelUsername_databaseName)
database_user:     (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
database_password: (whatever you picked)
```

Example:

```
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     localhost
database_port:     ~
database_user:     joe1337 
database_name:     joe1337_sym1
database_password: eHTb7%Pxa9
```

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2222

Comment: Thank you for your help.